# Install newer version of git?

Tags: git, version

I am trying to build setup-scripts for a Angstrom distribution on my Beaglebone Black. I use the following command:

```
MACHINE=beaglebone ./oebb.sh config beaglebone/
```

It give me the following error and says I need a newer version of git, but the version I have installed is newer?

```
root@beaglebone:~/angstrom/setup-scripts-master/setup-scripts-master# MACHINE=beaglebone ./oebb.sh config beaglebone/
No manual entry for git-log
Your installed version of git is too old, it lacks --no-abbrev. Please install 1.7.6 or newer
root@beaglebone:~/angstrom/setup-scripts-master/setup-scripts-master# git --version
git version 1.7.7
```

Any advice on how to get it working?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you have different git installations in your system. You will have to tell which one to use. Try doing a `which git` and then with the full path `/path/git --version`.

Answer (score 0):

remove all git instances and install 1.8

Comment: Was just strange for me that git installed via opkg on angstrom doesn't correspond to requirements of 1.7.6+?